# Best python solution to play ALL kinds of audio on Windows (and Linux)?

Tags: python, audio, mp3, m4a

I'm trying to write some scripts to play some of my music collection with python. Finding python modules that will play ogg and mp3 is not a problem. However, I'm having repeated failures with aac-encoded m4a files from iTunes (not DRM). pygame's audio machinery doesn't support them, so I tried pymedia:

```
a = pymedia.player.Player()
a.start()
a.startPlayback("myM4a.m4a", format='aac')
```

I've tried several versions of the last line of code, including omitting the format argument, changing the files to mp4, etc. mp3's work fine, however.

pymedia even claims to support aac encoded files, but the project appears to have been abandoned anyway.

Is there a good, up to date, solution for playing ALL types of audio in python? What is used by existing python media centers/players?

I should add that I intend to use this primarily on windows, so windows support for the library is a must, but cross-platform would obviously be preferable.

Comment: "ALL types of audio"? Including my format that I invented today? And that obsolete format from 23 years ago?

Comment: I understand your point, but considering the usual ubiquity of python modules for anything you could wish, I would think there'd be a decent all-encompassing audio library that plays formats that are widely in use. I mean, I can convert all my files to mp3s if need be, but considering all the audio players that have no trouble playing m4a's, I'm surprised at the level of python support for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the gStreamer API. It has plugins for many major audio types, is used by many audio players including Banshee and Rhythmbox and it can run on Linux, Windows and Mac. It has Python bindings as well as bindings for many other languages:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/bindings/

Comment: here's a [minimal code example that shows how to play an arbitrary (audio/video) media file using GStreamer](https://gist.github.com/zed/de5ebbc08805a941a7f7).

Answer (score 0):

MPlayer plays most known audio formats, and there's Python wrapper for it:

http://code.google.com/p/python-mplayer/

And a list of audio codecs supported by MPlayer:

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/codecs-status.html#ac